# fgets() returning empty string after socket_select

Tags: php, sockets

I've got a rather peculiar problem with sockets. The basis of the setup is a forking socket server, written in PHP. (I know, PHP, boo, etc, etc)

A very basic code sample of this would be...

```
$controlSockets = stream_socket_pair();
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if($pid == -1)
    throw new Exception("Fork error");
else if($pid) {
     fclose($controlSockets[0]);

     while(true) { 
          $read = array($controlSockets[1]);
          $write = array();
          $except = array();

          // Sleep for half a second if there's nothing to read
          while(stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0, 500000) > 0) { 
               $r = fgets($controlSockets[1]);
               echo "'$r'\n read from socket."; // This outputs ''
          }

          // Re-set the read array as stream_select alters the array
          $read = array($controlSockets[1]);
     }

} else {
     fclose($controlSockets[1]);
     // do some work ...
     sleep(5);
     // end of work ...
     $result = 'blah';
     fputs($controlSockets[0], $result);
     exit;
}
```

Now, the problem is that even though the socket is included in the read collection, however it returns an empty string, which in my knowledge should never happen, unless a feof was reached, or there actually was some content. 
Which there isn't for the first 5 seconds of execution.

The actual content that gets sent over arrives just fine, though.

Any clues as for what's going on?

(the code is above is pseudocode, no idea whether the actual sample works, but it's the general idea what's going on)

Comment: My bet is that the issue is that your real code doesn't write to the socket the same way your example code does. (A single write of less than PIPE_BUF bytes.) Confirm that your example code experiences the same issue. Otherwise it won't help identify your actual problem.

Comment: True enough. The general transmission size is anywhere between 13b and upwards to (theoretical) infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

- You specify timeout of 500 millis, but don't send input for 5 seconds, so select should really timeout on you and return zero.
- You don't check for errors returned from `` `stream_select() ``, which should be something like bellow according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) (signal interruptions, e.g.):

  `if (false === ($num_changed_streams = stream_select(...`

Comment: I know. This code is a real (really!) small subset of the code, all the error checking is stripped out.

The timeout of 5 seconds is roughly the time a forked process usually takes. The 500 ms is the polling interval. In the real situation, there are anywhere between 1 to 8 processes running simultaneously. In the real situation there's a posix_signal handler catching all SIGCHLD's (and SIGTRM, etc etc)

The point of this question is: Why is this socket getting returned in the stream_select even though there is no data to read, and it is NOT feof as I initially thought.

Comment: @Mark, post real code then, at least the part that does the select.

Answer (score 0):

Your code blows through error conditions. If `fgets` fails, you still output. Perhaps you're expecting `stream_select` to fail if the socket is closed, but it won't. It will just tell you that you need to check the socket.

I get:

```
'blah'
 read from socket.''
 read from socket.''
 [... repeats]
```